# Limiting TextBox Input dependent on Combobox Item Selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ComboBox that is bound to an ObservableCollection named "Attrs".
I also have a Textbox that is bound to "CustomValue".

Depending on which Attrs the user selects I am wanting the textbox to only accept certain characters. For example, if the Attrs.Name is "Numeric" I want the textbox to only accept numeric characters and if the Attrs.Name is "Text" I want the textbox to accept anything.

I have looked at both DataTemplates and Validation but I have failed to solve the issue or find a workaround.

Any ideas or links could help.

Comment: It might be easier to have two text boxes, one that validates numbers only, and one that validates text only. Then all you have to do is toggle the textboxes' visibility depending on what is selected in your combobox.

Comment: I decided to go with the two text boxes, so much easier to implement as I didn't have to bind any type just the visibility. I even decided to add another box. Thanks Henchbot!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment and ask if you tried this already but I don't have a high enough rep to comment yet, so I guess I will answer here. Also, unfortunately all I can give you is VB.Net code right now, not c#. But hopefully it at least helps.

You could create a custom control that inherits TextBox, and create a DependencyProperty that can be bound to the ComboBox's selected type:

```
Private Shared InputTypeProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputType", GetType(MyInputType), GetType(MyTextBox))

Public Property InputType As MyInputType
    Get
        Return GetValue(InputTypeProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As MyInputType)
        SetValue(InputTypeProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Then in your custom control, use the PreviewKeyDown event to handle the input based upon the InputType property on the control. Whenever an invalid character type is entered, set e.Handled to True and it will ignore the input.

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewKeyDown
    Select Case InputType
        'Handle input here
    End Select
End Sub
```

You may also want to make a PropertyChangedCallback in the dependency property to clear the TextBox if the type changes and it has invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Jon, I'll check and see if this works and get back to you!